# Android Unit Test: How to mock a listener that is sent as argument to an asynchronous method?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking

I have a method that receives a listener (interface) with onSuccess(result) and onFail(error) methods.
The tested method performs some actions (on another thread) and eventually calls the listener with an answer.

Example code for the method itself (not the test):

```
testedObject.performAsyncAction("some data", new IListener(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int result) {
        if (result == 1) { /* do something */ }
        else if (result == 2) { /* do something else */ }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Error error) {
        if (error.getMessage().equals("some error")) { /* do something */ }
        else if (error.getMessage().equals("another error")) { /* do something else */ }
    }
});
```

I want to have few tests on this method:

- Success when onSuccess(1) is called
- Success when onSuccess(2) is called
- Success when onFailure(new Error("some error")) is called
- Success when onFailure(new Error("another error")) is called

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For this case I use the Mockito Answer object. This would be a test for a success case:

```
Answer<Void> myAnswer = new Answer<Void>() {
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       Callback callback = (Callback) invocation.getArguments()[1]; // second argument in performAsyncAction 
       callback.onSuccess(1); // this would be 1 or 2 in your case
       return null;
    }
};

doAnswer(myAnswer).when(testedObject).performAsyncAction("some data", any(Callback.class));
```

For the failure case, just create another test with a different answer. For more info, check this [blog post](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html).

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to mock the performAsyncAction. I want to test it. Actually I have already figured out how how to mock the listener. Now the remaining part is how to set a timeout so that the test will wait until performAsyncAction will finish. (I know that it is better to avoid asynchronous test, but I have to test this asynchronous call with unit test here).

Comment: ok, so for the asynchronous unit tests what I use to do is replace the asynchronous element by a synchronous one in the test. That will make it much easier to test. For example, if I use a thread pool executor in my real code, in tests I replace it with a synchronous executor (it executes the runnable synchronously)

Comment: Yes, I replace the asynchronous methods with synchronous mocks as well. But sometimes I want to test the asynchronous functionality as is. This is my question. In iOS it is pretty easy to do...

Comment: @MichaelKessler I think you're looking for something like Awaitility: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility I've used it for testing async functionality and it's great. However, just take note that I don't think these are unit tests anymore when using Awaitlity but really are integration tests instead.